# Keyboard not showing up on EditText when return true

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

So I have added these lines inside `onCreate` such that when I click or touch the EditText it performs the action specified in `doSomething`. The problem is that with the code as presented below, after executing `doSomething` the keyboard doesn't show up. If I remove the `return true` inside the if block, then it works, but I don't understand why it fails to work if this line is included. So why does this happen?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    doSomething(editText);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `true` means touch is handled. You can see more from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener#onTouch(android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent))

Comment: I'm quite new to android and java so it didn't clarify much. Your link says this: True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise. As I understand I have to ```return true``` in order for the app to keep running, otherwise I would expect it to get stuck in this EditText. Instead the opposite happens.

Comment: Nope, if you return true onTouch will not continue to call super methods. If you return false onTouch will continue to invoke the super functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it happens because keyboard will show when `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` will be handled by `EditText` itself (not your custom `OnTouchListener`), so your `onTouch` should `return false` then

in general flag returned by `onTouch` informs framework that you've handled event - when you returning `true` then this event won't be propagated further (as already handled, "consumed"). if `false` returned then event still will be propagated to this `View` (and handled under the hood, check out particular sources how) or even to its parent if default implementation of `View` doesn't handle this action and also `return false`

this isn't the case of `EditText` - it is handling all events and like in first paragraph - `ACTION_UP` will show keyboard. but returning `true` in your first-in-order custom `OnTouchListener` prevent that

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Can I edit your answer? Because it was a bit difficult for me to follow so my editing can help other people at my level to understand it.

Comment: well, you always can, but more people (moderators) must approve it. if you want to change whole sentences and all the meaning (even simplifying) then your changes won't be accepted, as this will be your answer, not mine...